# Relative or Absolute path not opening

Tags: php

I am having a hard time trying to understand the procedure for relative pathing in php. I am working localhost using WAMP and everything I have tried after spending hours in google etc, just errors. The errors range from "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in" to stack errors. I have also tried Absolute paths but still the same result. I am at a loss as to how to proceed, so could really use some help. I have attached a list of procedures I have tried and any advice would be most welcome. Many thanks

```
In the admin header file:

<?php require_once('./Connections/connect.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('../../../Connections/connect.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('C:\wamp\www\domain/Connections/connect.php'); ?>

localhost\domain > root > index.php
                          header.php
                          footer.php
                          Connections\connect.php    

localhost\domain\admin > index.php
                         header.php
                         footer.php
                         form-inc.php

localhost\domain\admin\cp\users > index.php <--Users control panel in which I need to call 

                                               header.php & footer.php from the admin     

                                               directory which is where I am having the 

                                               problem.

PHP 5.3
WAMP
```

Comment: Tried this?: `<?php require_once('../../header.php'); ?>`

Comment: @Wallack sorry already have that <?php include('../../header.php'); ?>

Comment: Sorry, I may not understand correctly your problem. You want to include a file called sample.php in the header.php inside the admin folder? or you want to include the header.php from admin folder inside the index.php from the users folder?

Comment: @Wallack In the admin dir I have files header.php and footer.php in which header makes the db connections etc. I am trying to reference that file from: C:\wamp\www\domain\admin\cp\users

Answer (score 1):

Try this to avoid ambiguity `dirname(__FILE__)`

OR

if you're using PHP 5.3 or higher use this ->  `__DIR__` .

Usage -

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../filename.php';
```

OR -

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../../filename.php';
```

more from manuals - http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: You end the statement with ); where does the first ( go? Thanks

Comment: error with: <?php require __DIR__ . '../Connections/connect.php'; ?>

Comment: @user1532468 __DIR__ only exists with PHP >= 5.3

Comment: @user1532468 `var_dump(dirname(__FILE__));`  `var_dump(__DIR__);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31523/discussion-between-swapnesh-and-user1532468)

Comment: string 'C:\wamp\www\domain\admin' and I ran var_dump from C:\wamp\www\domain\admin\cp\users;